# how to do "Stop" "Back" and "Forward" with webbrowser in WP7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, browser

I have a WebBrowser in my application and show some pages in it.

But I cant Stop navigating progress and cant do Back and Forward in WebBrowser history

Please help me.